# How to make nuSoap work with CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, nusoap

I have already  put nusoap folder in cakephp vendor folder

../vendor/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php (it has more than one files)

I'm trying to include it as following but not working. What are the other alternatives?

App::import('vendor','nusoap');

Comment: nusoap is really outdated. If possible, it's almost always a better option to use the built-in PHP soap functions. At the very least, they are much faster. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Comment: If I'm not wrong built-in function doesn't support complex type. nusoap handles complex types very well and last version of nusoap was released only few months ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the file using this code

```
App::import('Vendor', 'nusoap', array('file' => 'nusoap'.DS.'lib'.DS.'nusoap.php'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an example here as to how to set it up: http://phpdev.ro/soap-webservices-in-cakephp.html

For the client(from the example):

1. import the nusoap library: App::import('Vendor','nusoap');
2. $client = new nusoap_client('http://yourdomain.com/webservices');
3. $result = $client->call('helloWorld', array('params' => array('name' => 'Andrew' ) ) );
4. print_r($result);